# Is it possible to win the "The Twice-Born Warlord" duel? (spoilers)

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

During the events of Chapter 3 in the "The Twice-Born Warlord" quest, you have the option for

> Amiri to infiltrate Armagh's camp and try to defeat him in a duel.

In order to do so, you have to stealth your way through and past

> a patrolling Defaced Sister.

However, during the duel

> when you're close to winning the duel, the Defaced Sister interferes and paralyzes Amiri in a cutscene, after which Armagh goes after her in a rage for disrupting the sanctity of a formal duel, and in the subsequent battle, he eventually escapes.

Is there a way to take out that person before the duel starts and avoid this outcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't.

If you start violence in the camp, it's noticed. And approaching a defaced sister will initiate the meeting with Armagh immediately.

Even, if you somehow managed it (e.g. by skilling heavily into stealth on Amiri and let her use bows as a main weapon, then maybe you could kill a sister quickly without anyone noticing), I don't think the game would react to it and just send another unknown defaced sister at you to play out that scene, because killing Armagh in that duel would completely change how this chapter plays out and cause you to miss a ton of content.

Comment: Drat. Figured at much, but thanks - the confirmation saves me a great deal of reloading and puzzling.